# Any shortcut or fast way to copy a file or folder to specified/favourite location?

Tags: windows

I have a folder called softwares where i copy all the softwares which looks good to me.
Now everytime i got new software to copy i have to copy it and then go to that folder and paste it.
Its time consuming.

Is any way or software by which i can add right click option

```
copy to specified folder
```

So that it can be done in seconds

Comment: I'm guessing windows by your other questions? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you'd benefit from [adding another option to your **Send To...** context menu item](http://www.dq.winsila.com/windows/windows-xp-tips/add-your-own-destinations-to-the-send-to-context-menu.html):

[image]

- In the Start Menu/Run dialog enter **sendto** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, this will open your SendTo folder.
- Right-click the folder you wish to add to the context menu and select **copy**.
- In the `SendTo` folder right-click and select **Paste Shortcut**.
- The item should now appear in the context menu so you can easily right-click your downloads and select **Send To -> Downloads** for example.

Comment: start, run, type sendto is easier :)

Comment: wow that worked the Send to folder was in
C:/users/username/appdata/roaming/microsoft/windows/sendto

Comment: Your higher rep gives you the ability to edit answers for a reason :)

Comment: @Mirage, yep, the `%APPDATA%` variable expands to the beginning of that.